# Vue.js v-for not rendering component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following issue, for some reason, the v-for will not render at all. Please find the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/tadeyemi/k6s4gv85/ I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working. Someone care to shed some light?

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Finds</h1>
  <div>
    <input ref="option">
  </div>
  <button v-if @click="addFind">
    New Find
  </button> 
  <p v-for="(option,idx) in options.slice(1)">
    <span @click="removeOption(idx+1)">Option{{idx+1}}: {{option}}</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript as follows:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [],
    count:0
  },
  methods: {
    addFind: function () {
    var msg = this.$refs.option.value;
    console.log(this.options);
    if( msg.trim() != "" ){
        this.count++;
        var i = this.count;
      this.options[i]= this.$refs.option.value.trim();
    }
    },
    removeOption:function(index){

    this.options.splice(index,1);
    this.count--;

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What value is stored in `options` at the time the component is rendered?

Comment: I ran it of JSFiddle and it showed me the option list, what behavior are you getting and hopping to achieve?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte On the fiddle, if you comment out the <pre> tag at the bottom, then it stops working, thi sis the bit I don't understand. I am logging the array and I can see that the array is populated.

Comment: @Bassie the options is empty to start with

Comment: @oluwatyson If options is empty, then the v-for it not going to render anything...

Comment: @oluwatyson I I think you are missing a condition fro your `v-if` as well -

Comment: @Bassie I agree with that, but once I start populating options using the addFind method, I was expecting the v-for to kick in and start rendering, please check out the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, but the most prominent is that you break some reactivity rules explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

Basically: `this.options.push(msg.trim());` would work, while `this.options[i]= this.$refs.option.value.trim();` **won't**

I edited the fiddle a little to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/63jyw7gz/

Comment: Thank you very much for that insight! Out of curiosity, what other parts of the code can be improved? I am quite new to Vue.js

Comment: Looks like the fiddle didn't save and I corrected this (https://jsfiddle.net/63jyw7gz/). Beside the reactivity, you were incrementing count variable before adding which resulted in first element being undefined (you were modifying a second element on an array that had no elements).